# Compact form for read and return frame from VideoCapture

Tags: c++, opencv

I have for example this easy function, but i would like make it more compact, have you suggestion for me?

```
VideoCapture camera = VideoCapture(0);

cv::Mat& OpenCvCamera::getFrame()
{
    Mat frame;
    camera >> frame;
    return frame;
}
```

I'd like to make it inline without using temporary variable "frame".

Is it possible?

Comment: What is your actual problem? Do you want to get rid of the copy? Because there is not actually a copy of pixel data happening.

Comment: what's wrong with read() ?

Comment: @nick Read doesn't change anything about the code. You just replace `camera >> frame;` with `camera.read(frame);`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I did not understand that through the read function it is possible to read the frame, thanks a lot.

Comment: have a look at the [,function](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html#a473055e77dd7faa4d26d686226b292c1)

Comment: @eike: It allows to get rid of the whole getFrame() construct from OP though, including the temp Mat. Makes for cleaner code.

Comment: @nick How is that facilitated by the move from `operator>>` to `read`?
`operator>>` is just syntactic sugar for `read` and does not change anything about this construct as far as I understand. You still need to create a temporary `Mat` to `read` into. At least in C++, the Python API directly returns a `Mat`

Comment: there are no "temporaries" of consequence. Mat objects are reference-counted. a "copy" costs nothing.

Comment: In OP's code, the function returns the reference to the local variable `frame`. This is wrong.
So, in this case, type of return value will be `Mat` (not `Mat&`).
If NRVO not applied, return value will become temporal object, and be copied (pixel data is shared, but not "no copy cost").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want to hide the existence of the VideoCapture object.
If so, just do only it.
i.e. Just wrap the VideoCapture::read(). No other change will not be needed.

```
//This object is invisible from the function user.
VideoCapture camera = VideoCapture(0);

//Type of this function (argument and return) is same as VideoCapture::read().
bool OpenCvCamera::getFrame( cv::Mat &frame )
{   return camera.read( frame );    }
```

Comment: Or, if `OpenCvCamera` is class name, add operator >> to the class.

Comment: By the way, I prefer convenience over "Compact".
So I think that writing the wrapper function using `grab()` and `retrieve()` is better way.
 (If `retrieve()` does not fail if `grab()` succeeds, then we can say that the specification of the wrapper function is "the contents of the arguments are not changed on failure".)

Answer (score 0):

[cv::VideoCapture::read](https://%5Bhttps://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html#a473055e77dd7faa4d26d686226b292c1%5D) is probably what you're looking for.

Allows you to get rid of the whole `getFrame()` function:

```
VideoCapture camera = VideoCapture(0);
cv::Mat frame;
camera.read(frame);
```

Comment: Would you mind showing how the code from the question is inlined without temporaries using `read`?

Comment: > "Allows you to get rid of the whole getFrame() function." how?

Comment: How is that different from `VideoCapture camera = VideoCapture(0); cv::Mat frame; camera >> frame;`?

Comment: @eike: OP can now use .read() in any place he would normaly have used getFrame(). That's the whole (and only) point, as apparently he tries to avoid the stream operator.

Comment: But he could have used `>>` in any place he would normally have used getFrame(). So how did the move from `>>` to `read` change anything in the slightest bit? The inlining if the function is in no way related to changing `>>` to `read`.

Comment: The question stated he wanted to inline and avoid temporaries, no stream operator is mentioned.

Comment: there are no temporaries of consequence. Mats are reference-counted. a copy costs nothing.